# will MySQL highly frequently scheduled query affect database performance?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, sql-tuning

I have a couple of  queries executing every 10 seconds, and both tables are using 'text' data type. I wonder if this will affect database performance? One table is full scan, another one has 'order by' and 'limit' clauses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your HW. If you have some poor one, that it will affect DB performance. If you have some high-end machine, I think, It wont be noticed. But either way, it will slow things down.

However, have 10seconds queries, looks suspisious. Do you have correct oprimalization and correctly written query ?

Comment: Thanks. This query just keeps looking at some other thing, once something was changed, a notice will send to other process. I am not the query designer, just found these 2 queries were written into mysql slow log file  frequently.